# Recognize the row that the button was pressed

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

Every 'btn1' call the same method.

[image: Example]
PS: This is an `UITableView`

I want to know how to get from which row the button was pressed. I tried to do a loop in every button an set the buttons tag differently from the last one:

```
// Handle the buttons tag
int tagCount = 100;

// mainArray is the array of the tableView
for (int i = 0; i < [self.mainArray count]; i++) {
    // I created a NSIndexPath to access the tableView cells
    NSIndexPath *nowIndex = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0];
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[(UITableView *)self.view cellForRowAtIndexPath:nowIndex];

    // I set the button tag as the 'int';
    UIButton *shareButton = (UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
    [shareButton setTag:tagCount];

    tagCount++;
}
```

But the tag's still equal to 100;

Any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the buttons are `UIButton` instances then set the tag property (maybe to the row number). In the event method you can test the tag property to see which button was pressed.

Comment: That's what I thought: Do a loop in every row and set the buttons tag as `(the last row tag)+1`, but it's not working. Take a look at the code I just added to the question, please.

Comment: In tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath when you fill out the cell and set the UIButton as the accessoryView, set the tag at that point to indexPath.row. There is not a single UITableViewCell for every row. The UITableView only creates enough cells for what is on the screen. You could create the buttons ahead of time (in viewDidLoad) or create them lazily in cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: That's a great idea: 
`UIButton *shareButton = (UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:100];    [shareButton setTag:[indexPath row]];`

Comment: It's setting the tag normally, but when the button is pressed the `[sender tag]` isn't right. That's really weird.

Comment: Okay, here's my solution: I removed the button from the Interface Builder, made it totally programmatically, and setting the button tag as `[indexPath row]` it worked great. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can replace your `UIButton` instance with a `UIImageView` with a regular and optionally a highlighted image, and set it to your table view cell's `accessoryView`.  Then implement `UITableViewDelegate`'s `tableView:accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:` method.  That way, you do not have to deal with tags, or storing reference to the button.  This method should be adequate if you do not require any UIButton interactions like selected states, or other gestures.

Comment: That's a great idea, but the problem is that I need to change the `accessoryView` position.